# SSIS missing data from SQL table using Fast Load

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a bit of a problem. When I set up a SSIS package and i fire it off it shows me the amount of rows that is going into the SQL table, but when I query the table there is almost 40000 rows missing from what the last count was after the conditional split that I have in the package.

[image: SSIS package]

[image]

What causes this problem? Even if I have it on normal table or view it still does the same thing. But here I have to use the **fastload** option as it is a lot of source files being loaded. This is only testing before sending it to production and I am stuck at the moment. Is there a way I can work around this problem and get all the data that is supposed to be pumped into the table. please also take note that in the conditional split it removes any NULL values as seen in first picture.

Comment: Did u try removing `FastLoad` option and running your package just to test it ?

Comment: @praveen I have done this yes. results are exactly the same as with the fastload.

Comment: turn on SSIS logging check the row count or see if u have placed any trigger in the destination table ? Try to see if the same rows are getting skipped in the destination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Error Output (under Connection Manager and Mappings) within Destination Component.  If the Error setting is set to Ignore Failure or Redirect Row, the component will succeed, but only the successful rows will be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data source? Try checking your data and make sure you don't have any terminators stored in one of the rows.